# ImportError: No module named 'PyQt5.QtQuick'

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

I have installed PyQt5 in my Ubuntu 14.04.04 LTS by using the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pyqt5
```

But when I run the following statement in python IDLE, I got errors. How to solve it?

```
>>> from PyQt5.QtQuick import QQuickView, QQuickItem
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'PyQt5.QtQuick'
```

Comment: A: you have made sure you are using the same version of python that you installed it, and B: can you do `import PyQt5` without error?

Comment: `sudo apt-get install python3-pyqt5.qtquick`.

Comment: @ekhumoro Thanks boss. I got the point. :)

Answer (score 6):

For this kind of error I have found a solution from the above comment. Just install relevant package with apt-get:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pyqt5.qtquick
```